# Cant get any results from ES. No errors

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have such mapping -

```
    "type": "nested",
    "include_in_parent": true,
    "properties": {
        "value": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "Technical": {
                    "properties": {
                        "techlocation": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "techname22": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

When I run match_all query I get this -

```
"metadata": [
{
  "value": {
      "Technical": [
         {
             "techname22": "test"
         },
         {
             "techlocation": "usa"
         }
      ]
   }
}
],
```

But I cant query it with(Also tried just Technical.techlocation:(loc)) and other ways.dddddddddd -

```
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
              "query_string" : {
                "query": "metadata.value.Technical.techlocation:(loc)",
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "analyze_wildcard": true
            }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

There is nothing more to tell really.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an older ES version so the actual syntax of this query may differ a bit but you'll need to use the `nested` query when searching on `nested` fields:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "metadata.value",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "metadata.value.Technical.techlocation:(usa)",
          "default_operator": "AND",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```